# Валидация параметров метода через аннотации

Tags: java, рефлексия, аннотации, aspectj

Хочу реализовать следующий функционал: отмечать аннотацией параметры методов, нужно реализовать обработчик аннотаций таким образом, чтобы при запуске этих методов происходила валидация их параметров. Могу ли я используя аспектно-ориентированное программирование (Spring, aspectJ ...), каким-то образом получать параметры методов в свои советы?

Comment: Да, можете в своих нефинальных классах, которые являются частью спринговского контейнера. Используйте @ Around или @ Before . Но методы строки не получится.

Comment: Я поправил вопрос, подскажите пожалуйста пару фраз для гугления как в советах использовать параметры аннотируемого метода.

Comment: Зачем аспекты? Используйте прокси

Comment: @Андрей Коцизкий https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params 
Параграф "Determining Argument Names". Там показано, как получить аргументы метода, к которому применяется advice.

Comment: GenCloud, юзая прокси мне нужно будет каждому классу со своими валидирующими аннотациями создовать прокси объект, а через аоп я сразу срез могу определить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете получить аргументы метода, используя args.

Например есть интерфейс:

```
package com.service;

    public interface EmpService {
        void removeEmployee(Integer id);
    }
```

И аспект для него:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ValidationAspect {

    @Before(value = "execution(* com.service.EmpService.removeEmployee(*)) && args(id)")
    public void validateId(Integer id) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(id, "Id can't be null");
    }
}
```